# Best place to keep a viewcount in for a cached objecct in PHP?

Tags: php, caching, memcached

My application caches pages so no unnecessary requests to the database are made. They are cached as files in the filesystem with appropriate names (their unique identifiers).

I need to be able to keep view counts for those cached pages, and one way is storing them in **memcached** and incrementing the values by one every time. When the cache is cleaned, the values are collected and updated in the database using a bulk query.

I'm not sure this is a good idea, and as I've noticed that accessing memcached slows it down. Are there any better solutions?

**Edit:** I'm not caching little bytes of data, I am caching HTML pages, and a lot of them. There are about 30 pages for each user, and with a million users the amount of data that needs caching will be massive.

Comment: Why do you need to store the viewcount?

Comment: Because it is an image / note storage service and having a viewcount would be nice.

Comment: . They are cached as files in the filesystem with appropriate names (their unique identifiers). => you should try to avoid touching the disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup a cronjob to run nightly that parses the access log file and updates the counts.  I'm not sure about the memcache method (have not tried it), but if you resorted to updating the database every single request, I don't think it would be very efficient. Update queries are expensive, and updating a count column would involve locking, at minimum, the row.

Alternatively, you could insert a record in a "views" table for each view, then run a cronjob nightly to aggregate the view count, add it to a "views" column in the pages table, and afterwards purge the records it aggregated.

Then, there is always Google Analytics as well if you are ok with resorting to a 3rd party.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you on update queries, but out of all the methods memcached still seems to be the most efficient. The cache cleanup is run via cron by the way.

Comment: What happens in the off-chance that your server crashes?  Since memory is volatile, you'd lose track of any page views.  Of course, they may not be that important to you, but just asking.

Comment: They are more of a convenience to users. I don't really care if I lose them.

Answer (score 1):

Caching has its flaws, the main one being exactly what you are describing. You either get fast read times when using a cache, to the detriment of up-to-date data; or get slower read times when not using a cache, but with up-to-date data.

In my opinion, updating the cache in real-time kind of nullify the point of caching in the first place. You're better off writing the database in real-time and reading from the cache. You just have to update the cache in a timely fashion to keep the frontend as up-to-date as possible (this latest statement being highly relative).

Comment: I don't think he was talking about displaying a view counter on the website.

Comment: @simshaun: It doesn't make a difference. A cache solution (i.e.: memcache) is not best used for updating a counter in real-time (whether you want to display it or not). A database engine is best suited for that task: it usually has faster write times because its main purpose is storage. A caching solution's purpose, on the other hand, is to read fast.

Comment: But the reason I use filesystem caching is not to bother the database with lookups in the first place. Using a database will require tons of UPDATE queries each second.

Comment: @Nick: Filesystem I/O times are slower than UPDATE queries, especially if you use prepared statements. Filesystem operations also require lookups, you know. Besides, databases are MEANT to be looked up.

Comment: To access the database in a desired manner I also need to bootstrap the application core which is massive. And to lookup an entry I need to perform 4 queries. In this case filesystem is faster.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure this is a good idea, and
>   as I've noticed that accessing
>   memcached slows it down. Are there any
>   better solutions?

### incr/decr

I don't understand? They have [incr/decr](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#incr/decr) commands in memcached especially for this which should be lightning fast.

I looked up some [benchmarks](http://capttofu.livejournal.com/16147.html):

```
[patg@vidya perl]$ ./memtest.pl -l 1000
Operation  Cache::Memcached libmemcached   C::M/libmem %  libmem/C::M % 
set        0.083264         0.061046       136.40         73.32         
get        0.164471         0.054142       303.78         32.92         
replace    0.081321         0.060575       134.25         74.49         
increment  0.080247         0.056108       143.02         69.92         
decrement  0.07893          0.052921       149.15         67.05         
delete     0.07416          0.056302       131.72         75.92         
total      0.562456         0.341165       164.86         60.66         
[patg@vidya perl]$ ./memtest.pl -l 10000
Operation  Cache::Memcached libmemcached   C::M/libmem %  libmem/C::M % 
set        0.838437         0.63161        132.75         75.33         
get        1.676396         0.552247       303.56         32.94         
replace    0.846411         0.615959       137.41         72.77         
increment  0.812054         0.538519       150.79         66.32         
decrement  0.787005         0.532655       147.75         67.68         
delete     0.744186         0.515013       144.50         69.20         
total      5.7046           3.386127       168.47         59.36         
[patg@vidya perl]$ ./memtest.pl -l 100000
Operation  Cache::Memcached libmemcached   C::M/libmem %  libmem/C::M % 
set        8.436679         6.469707       130.40         76.69         
get        16.641089        5.553091       299.67         33.37         
replace    8.438474         6.239129       135.25         73.94         
increment  8.110361         5.765341       140.67         71.09         
decrement  8.272824         5.615784       147.31         67.88         
delete     7.648199         5.32153        143.72         69.58         
total      57.547827        34.964783      164.59         60.76
```

### Contention

Are you also using mysql? Maybe you have [contention](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention.html) on mysql, that's why slow? because incr/decr should be fast?

Comment: It isn't much faster than going a get and a set. Just tested it.

Comment: i know, but get/set commands are extremely fast => http://antirez.com/post/update-on-memcached-redis-benchmark.html. => Memcached was serving 200k SETs per second (FAST?)

Comment: It still causes a 30ms lag at its slowest. (At 200 concurrent requests)

Comment: SQL doesn't even get touched, because the cache is stored in a filesystem. Not using memcache gives those extra 30ms.

Comment: Cache stored in filesystem?? Not memory?? How are you using that?? Because that's what could make run slow? Also what kind of memcached client are you using. You should use libmemcached with persistent connections for kickas performance?

Comment: you should use this memcached client(if not) in conjunction with php because it compiles as c code inside PHP for the best performance => http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

Comment: I'm using the PHP one, without persistent connections. I can't store 6 GB of cache in RAM. Our RAM is only 16 GB and a lot of it is needed for Apache.

Comment: First of you need persistent connections(C/PECL) for real good performance because opening connections is expensive(relative) and memcached can handle a lot of open connections(designed that way).

Also I should avoid you not touch the disc for the counting every time you incr counter. Write counter only to disc every x minutes(because I don't think it is really bad if counter is a little bit of).



maybe you should consider nginx which uses less ram because of event-loop(less context-switching)?